# How does a car at the top of a loop de loop experience a downward normal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

For the car to experience a downward normal force, shouldn’t there be an upward force that the car exerts on the track? How does that force originate. I don’t see how the car really exerts a force on the track. 
Or is there any other reason why there is a downward normal force on the car?
Also, I suppose normal force exists so that one object cannot displace another object from its place... but in this case, the car can’t possibly take the track’s place?

Comment: Hi Richie Harvy, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 3):

The normal force is what's causing the car to change direction.  The car "tries" to move in a straight line, but it encounters the slope of the track. Looking at it in tiny time steps, it is as if the car collides elastically with the track in each time step, changing the direction of the car.

The force of the track on the car is equal and opposite to the force of the car on the track by Newton's third law.

Comment: Just wanted to ask, can the normal force at the top of a loop ever be 0 but still be in circular motion?

Comment: Why do I set normal force as 0 to find the minimum speed for the car to be in circular motion?

Comment: Below min sped the car falls away from the track, above min speed the car is pushed against the track.

Answer (score 0):

your overall question--

*For the car to experience a downward normal force, shouldn’t there be an upward force that the car exerts on the track? How does that force originate. I don’t see how the car really exerts a force on the track.*

since the car is moving in circle you need to consider centrifugal force (in reference frame of car) which is $\cfrac{mv^2}{R}$($R$ is radius of circular track) , this amount force is exerted by car on the loop so , you need to consider  a normal force exerted by track.(other wise the track would jump or car would go through the track shooting up parabolically
)

so at top of loop the equation ,for the car to not fall down would be by equilibrium of forces --

$N$ $+$ $mg$ $=$ $\cfrac{mv^2}{R}$ ---------(where $N$ is normal force exerted by track)

Comment: Why will the car shoot up vertically? Doesn’t it have 0 vertical velocity at the top most point? Shouldn’t it follow a parabolic path when it leaves the track?

Comment: How can the normal force be equal and opposite to the centrifugal force? Shouldn’t it be less than that?

Comment: when did I say 'normal force be equal and  to centrifugal force' , see the last equation there's $mg$ in equation as well. and normal force is  opposite to centrifugal force(pseudo force), but its in direction of centripetal force to make car move in circle.

Comment: the equation can also be viewed as , that normal force and $mg$ provides necessary centripetal force, however this is true for inertial reference frame, I have stated it for non inertial frame( frame of car) ,in this $\frac{mv^2}{R}$ is an pseudo force i.e centrifugal

Comment: and yes car would follow parabolic path, for simplicity I had stated those , but I would edit that one .

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot @maverick!